# Access Underlying Physics Engine with Python

Tags: python, physics, collision

I need to detect when (at which frame(s)) collisions occur in my rigid body simulation. I have tried a few tricks (see below), but ideally I would like to use the physics engine to get accurate information.

Currently, this is how I am detecting collisions (essentially, I'm testing whether any vertex on object one is within a threshold distance of object two):

````
import bpy
import mathutils

collision_states = {}

def distance_to_face(vert, face, obj):
    face_center = obj.matrix_world @ face.center
    face_normal = obj.matrix_world.to_3x3() @ face.normal
    distance = abs(mathutils.geometry.distance_point_to_plane(vert, face_center, face_normal))
    return distance

def check_vertex_face_distance(obj1, obj2, threshold):
    for vert in obj1.data.vertices:
        vert_world_co = obj1.matrix_world @ vert.co
        for face in obj2.data.polygons:
            distance = distance_to_face(vert_world_co, face, obj2)
            if distance < threshold:
                return True
    return False

def detect_collisions(scene, threshold):
    global collision_states
    for obj1 in scene.objects:
        if obj1.type == 'MESH':
            for obj2 in scene.objects:
                if obj2.type == 'MESH' and obj1 != obj2:
                    pair_key = frozenset([obj1, obj2])
                    collision = check_vertex_face_distance(obj1, obj2, threshold)
                    
                    if collision and (pair_key not in collision_states or not collision_states[pair_key]):
                        frame = scene.frame_current
                        print(f"Collision started between {obj1.name} and {obj2.name} at frame {frame}")
                        collision_states[pair_key] = True
                    elif not collision and pair_key in collision_states and collision_states[pair_key]:
                        frame = scene.frame_current
                        print(f"Collision ended between {obj1.name} and {obj2.name} at frame {frame}")
                        collision_states[pair_key] = False

def collision_callback(scene):
    threshold = 0.04
    detect_collisions(scene, threshold)

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.clear()
bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(collision_callback)
```
````

Comment: i would use BGE for that. You even don't need python to get the collision there.

Comment: @Chris, thank you for the idea! I was under the impression that BGE was no longer part of Blender. I did look into it but couldn't see how I could integrate it into my workflow

Comment: https://upbge.org/#/ but I've never tested it.

Comment: @lemon thanks—I'll give it a shot!